# Explain the result of sizeof operator for a union containing structures

Tags: c, sizeof, structure, unions

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct mystruct
{
    char cc;
    float abc;
};
union sample
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
    double d;
    struct mystruct s1;
};
int main()
{
    union sample u1;
    int k;
    u1.s1.abc=5.5;
    u1.s1.cc='a';

    printf("\n%c %f\n",u1.s1.cc,u1.s1.abc);
    k=sizeof(union sample);
    printf("%d\n\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

The size of operator is returning `8` I am still able to access the structure elements, more than one at a time and still the `sizeof` operator is returning the max size of primitive data types i assume. Why is this behavior? Is the size actually allocated is `8`? and the `sizeof` is returning a wrong value? Or is the actual allocated size is `8`? Then how is the structure accommodated?? If we allocate an array of unions using `malloc` and `sizeof` will it allocate enough space in such case? Please eloborate.

Comment: `sizeof(double) == 8` And don't forget about structure alignment/padding.

Comment: The structure needs a size of `9` right??

Comment: @sasidhar, One modification to your program: http://ideone.com/2HhTn

Comment: @sasidhar: 9? Where did 9 come from? `sizeof(float)` is 4. `sizeof(char) ` is 1. So, your struct needs at least 5 bytes. But for alignment purposes it occupies 8. Why 9?

Comment: @sasidhar: what do you get for `sizeof(float)`?

Comment: @AndreyT, 1 for the char and 8 for the float or something, I guess. Of course, as demonstrated in the ideone sample, that's not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the size of the union is the size of its biggest member. The biggest member is [likely] your struct member as well as the `double` member. Both have size 8. So, as `sizeof` correctly told you, the size of the union is indeed 8.

Why do you find it strange? Why do you call 8 "wrong value"?

Comment: how does it accommodate the `structure` member within??

Comment: @sasidhar: What do you mean by your "how"? The size of your struct member is probably 8 (check it). The size of the union is 8. So, the union is indeed big enough to accommodate the struct member. Where do you see the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
struct mystruct
{
    char cc;   //1 -byte 
    //3 bytes Added here for Padding
    float abc; //size of float is 4-bytes
};
```

so 1 + 3 + 4 = 8 bytes.
 
We knew the memory will be allocated for largest member of union. In our case both sizeof(double) = sizeof(struct mystruct) is 8.

Answer (score 1):

A union is used to place multiple members at the same memory location - you can't use more than one member at a time. All of them overlap, so the size of the union is the same as the size of the largest member.

Answer (score 0):

Union types are special structures which allow access to the same memory using different type descriptions. one could, for example, describe a union of data types which would allow reading the same data as an integer, a float or a user declared type

```
union 
{
    int i;
    float f;
    struct 
    {
     unsigned int u;
     double d;
    } s;
} u;
```

In the above example the total size of u is the size of u.s (which is the sum of the sizes of u.s.u and u.s.d), since s is larger than both i and f. When assigning something to u.i, some parts of u.f may be preserved if u.i is smaller than u.f.