# Structures containing conditional fields in C

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to implement a protocol standard and I'm having a bit of trouble with their concept of conditional fields. They are defined as fields that are present or absent depending on some condition. The example they give is as follows:

```
    uint16 Pressure;
    enum VehicleType { car = 0, motorbike = 1};
    struct TirePressureInfo {
                    VehicleType type;
                    select (type)
                    {
                    case car:
                            Pressure frontLeft;
                            Pressure frontRight;
                            Pressure rearLeft;
                            Pressure rearRight;
                    case motorbike:
                            Pressure front;
                            Pressure rear;
                    }
            }
```

I'm unaware of anyway to make this work in C, or if it's even possible. I can't think of anyway to implement this. One thing to note, is this is going to be implemented in a Linux Kernel Module, so I'm a bit restricted there as well.

```
            struct {
                    uint8 protocol_version;
                    ContentType type;
                    select (type) {
                    case unsecured :
                    opaque data<var>;
                    case signed, signed_partial_payload,
                    signed_external_payload:
                    SignedData signed_data;
                    case signed_wsa:
                    SignedWsa signed_wsa;
                    case encrypted :
                    EncryptedData encrypted_data;
                    case crl_request :
                    CrlRequest crl_request;
                    case crl :
                    Crl crl;
                    case other_value:
                    opaque data<var>;
                    }
            } 1609Dot2Data;




    struct {
            SignerIdentifierType type;
            select (type) {
            case self: ;
            case certificate_digest_with_ecdsap224 :
            case certificate_digest_with_ecdsap256 :
                    HashedId8 digest;
                    opaque data<var>;
            case certificate:
                    Certificate certificate;
            case certificate_chain:
                    Certificate certificates<var>;
            case certificate_digest_with_other_algorithm :
                    Signer signer;
                    PKAlgorithm algorithm;
                    HashedId8 digest;
            case other_value:
                    opaque id<var>;
            }
    } SignerIdentifier;
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a [`union`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions).

Comment: Either union or an uber-structure containing all possible fields. There is no such thing as a conditional field in C.

Comment: Unions are just representing data in different ways, right? I need different fields contained in the structure, not just different ways of representing them.

Comment: Well, Google is your friend with finding out how to use unions, but basically they just are a way of re-interpreting the same area of memory. It saves from wasting memory for fields that aren't used depending on your vehicle type, but it's only a concern is you are on a platform that could benefit from the memory savings (and how many structures for tire pressure info you will have).

Comment: If you refuse using a `union`, your question is not clear. Using different fields at the same time means you need a `struct`.

Comment: The pressure was just an example given by IEEE. The actual structure will contain fields of different data types. I'm updating the question with their required data type.

Comment: Still a `union`. The fields in each of the cases can be represented by a seperate member within the one `union`.

Comment: I don't think I can use a union. There are instances where there's not just one field associated with the condition. It can be 3 different types of variables inside, so like signed_wsa would contain an int, double and float. encrypted_data would contain just int and double. How can I accomplish that with a union?

Comment: `signed_wsa` would be a struct. Which is a perfectly valid type for a union member. That is, a struct within a union within a struct.

Comment: Oh my! Think recursive!

Comment: Well worth looking at Neil Brown's kernel design patterns articles on LWN eg) https://lwn.net/Articles/446317/ discusses data structures for file systems, which like motorbikes & car's may have common parts and specialised.  It may be better to have a car, which embeds a vehicle struct, rather than have vehicle with union of car/bike.

Comment: @kaylum What about when each type requires a different number of fields?

Comment: You can have a `union` of `struct`s.

Comment: Each union member can be a struct and each struct has different fields.

Comment: I understand I can have a union of structs. It seems as if everyone is ignoring the part where I mentioned that the select won't have the same number of fields for each case. Some could be just a single field, other cases it could be ten. I can't figure out how to do a case like that with a union.

Comment: I'm adding another example.

Comment: That new example doesn't change the principle. It just means you have another union inside your `SignerIdentifier` struct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`union`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions):

```
uint16 Pressure;
enum VehicleType { CAR = 0, MOTORBIKE = 1};
struct TirePressureInfo {
  VehicleType type;
  union {
    struct {
      Pressure frontLeft;
      Pressure frontRight;
      Pressure rearLeft;
      Pressure rearRight;
    } car;
    struct {
      Pressure front;
      Pressure rear;
    } motorbike;
  } data;
};
```

So then you can set it like:

```
struct TirePressureInfo info;
info.type = CAR;
info.data.car.frontLeft  = 35;
info.data.car.frontRight = 35;
info.data.car.rearLeft   = 32;
info.data.car.rearRight  = 32;
```

or if you want to define a `MOTORBIKE`:

```
struct TirePressureInfo info;
info.type = MOTORBIKE;
info.data.motorbike.front = 38;
info.data.motorbike.rear  = 40;
```

When you read from it, you should check the `type`:

```
switch ( info.type ) {
case CAR:
    /* read info.data.car fields */
    break;
case MOTORBIKE:
    /* read info.data.motorbike fields */
    break;
default:
    /* Some data integrity problem */
}
```

If you are certain that you only ever need a `struct car` or `struct motorbike` at a time (depending on the value of `type`), then there is no need to waste space by having every `TirePressureInfo` include *both* `struct car`'s fields and `struct motorbike`'s fields.  Using a `union` makes the `struct car` and `struct motorbike` occupy the same place in memory.  The actual size of the `union` is the [greater of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642859/explain-the-result-of-sizeof-operator-for-a-union-containing-structures).  This just gives you different ways to read and write to the same place in memory.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me. It's a bit difficult trying to visualize it, as I have very little experience with unions.